# Converting xml node string to strip out nodes

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table that has a column called `RAW DATA` of type `NVARCHAR MAX`, which is a dump from a web service.  Here is a sample of 1 data line:

```
<CourtRecordEventCaseHist>
    <eventDate>2008-02-11T06:00:00Z</eventDate>
    <eventDate_TZ>-0600</eventDate_TZ>
    <histSeqNo>4</histSeqNo>
    <countyNo>1</countyNo>
    <caseNo>xxxxxx</caseNo>
    <eventType>WCCS</eventType>
    <descr>Warrant/Capias/Commitment served</descr>
    <tag/>
    <ctofcNameL/>
    <ctofcNameF/>
    <ctofcNameM/>
    <ctofcSuffix/>
    <sealCtofcNameL/>
    <sealCtofcNameF/>
    <sealCtofcNameM/>
    <sealCtofcSuffix/>
    <sealCtofcTypeCodeDescr/>
    <courtRptrNameL/>
    <courtRptrNameF/>
    <courtRptrNameM/>
    <courtRptrSuffix/>
    <dktTxt>Signature bond set</dktTxt>
    <eventAmt>0.00</eventAmt>
    <isMoneyEnabled>false</isMoneyEnabled>
    <courtRecordEventPartyList>
        <partyNameF>Name</partyNameF>
        <partyNameM>A.</partyNameM>
        <partyNameL>xxxx</partyNameL>
        <partySuffix/>
        <isAddrSealed>false</isAddrSealed>
        <isSeal>false</isSeal>
    </courtRecordEventPartyList>
</CourtRecordEventCaseHist>
```

It was suppose to go in a table, with the node names representing the column names. The table it's going to is created, I just need to exract the data from this row to the table. I have 100's of thousands records like this.  I was going to copy to a xml file, then import.  But there is so much data, I would rather try and do the work within the DB.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post your table structure? How is `courtRecordEventPartyList` mapping to a single column? Is there more than one table?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle? Each of their syntaxes for handling XML is different.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the table with all the required columns.

Then, use your favorite scripting language to load the table! Mine being groovy, here is what I'd do:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(/* SQL connection here*/)

sql.eachRow("select RAW_DATA from TABLE_NAME") { row ->
    String xmlData = row."RAW_DATA"
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlData)
    def date = root.eventDate
    def histSeqNo = root.histSeqNo
    //Pull out all the data and insert into new table!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer to this, I'm sure there is more than one way of doing this.  But this is what I got to work.  Thanks for everyone's help.

```
SELECT 
  pref.value('(caseNo/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as CaseNumber,
  pref.value('(countyNo/text())[1]', 'int') as CountyNumber
```

FROM
   dbo.CaseHistoryRawData_10 CROSS APPLY
      RawData.nodes('//CourtRecordEventCaseHist') AS CourtRec(pref)